# Unable to receive invocation in blackberry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, signals-slots

I followed the developer site's information to send an invocation and receive an invocation. But receiving invocation raises an error when building.

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/receiving_invocation.html

The error is located at the following code section

```
connectResult = QObject::connect(invokeManager, 
    SIGNAL(invoked(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)),
    &myApp, SLOT(onInvoke(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)));
```

What is "myApp" in this code section?

Answer (score 0):

This is your application.  Hopefully the following code ample explains this:

```
MyApp::MyApp(bb::cascades::Application *app)
: QObject(app)
{
    _invokeManager = new bb::system::InvokeManager(this);

    // Listen to incoming invocation requests
    connect(_invokeManager, SIGNAL(invoked(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)), this, SLOT(handleInvoke(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)));
    connect(_invokeManager, SIGNAL(cardResizeRequested(const bb::system::CardResizeMessage&)), this, SLOT(resized(const bb::system::CardResizeMessage&)));
    connect(_invokeManager, SIGNAL(cardPooled(const bb::system::CardDoneMessage&)), this, SLOT(pooled(const bb::system::CardDoneMessage&)));
```